Do we need to separate the combined tag pohlig-hellman for Pohlig Hellman Cipher and Pohlig-Hellman Algorithm
We have a tag pohlig-hellman with 32 question that stands for both

Pohlig-Hellman symmetric cipher and
the Pohlig–Hellman algorithm for discrete logarithm

Nicely; the cipher's security relay on the hardness of the discrete logarithm and Pohlig–Hellman algorithm is one of the attack methods.
Should we create two tags; like pohlig-hellman and pohlig-hellman-cipher

Yes, we need to separate the tag, since;

A tag should represent one subject and currently, the tag contains two subjects.
fill reasons...


And the two subjects really have little to do with each other (other than being discovered by the same people)

No, keep it as it is, since;

both the cipher and the algorithm are based on the same mathematical problem;
fill reasons...

